# python write header to csv, all headers in one cell

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write headers to a csv file, but all the headers are written in one cell. Can any one help me with that?

```
total_production_cost_w = open('Total_Production_Cost.csv','w')    
headers = ['Company', 'Pool', 'Steam Cost', 'Nuclear Cost', 'Turbine Cost', 'Variable O & M', 'Emission Fee Tax', 'Hydro Cost', 'Hydro Maintenance Cost', 'Total Production Cost']
total_production_cost_w.write('\t'.join(headers) + '\n')
total_production_cost_w.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a *Comma*-Separated Value file you want to write, then you should use a comma as separator instead of a tab, maybe ? :-)

Try:

```
total_production_cost_w.write(','.join(headers) + '\n')
```

instead of:

```
total_production_cost_w.write('\t'.join(headers) + '\n')
```

Or, better: use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: I vote for the csv module.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is you use TAB to separate the columns. For csv, replace `\t` with `,`. But if you are dealing with csv, I highly recommend the `csv` module:

```
import csv

headers = ['Company', 'Pool', 'Steam Cost', 'Nuclear Cost', 'Turbine Cost', 'Variable O & M', 'Emission Fee Tax', 'Hydro Cost', 'Hydro Maintenance Cost', 'Total Production Cost']
with open('Total_Production_Cost.csv','w') as total_production_cost_w:
    writer = csv.writer(total_production_cost_w)
    writer.writerow(headers)
```